# Degree of Hessian surface invariant under linear transformations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

Given a surface $V(f) \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ for a homogeneous polynomial $f$ of degree $d$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$ and a linear transformation $g \in SL(n+1)$. Is the degree of the Hessian $H_f = V(\det (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}))$ of $f$ equal to the degree of the Hessian $H_{f\circ g} = V(\det (\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}))$ of $f\circ g$? If so, why? If not, are there any restrictions under which this holds?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x_0,...,x_n)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$, its second partial derivatives $\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$ have degree $d-2$, so that the Hessian determinant $Hess(f)=det(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j})$ is homogeneous of  degree $(d-2)(n+1)$ or is zero.
Since $f\circ g$ is also homogeneous of degree $d$, we see that  $Hess(f\circ g)$  is homogeneous of  degree $(d-2)(n+1)$ or is zero.

**Conclusion**
Your  varieties $H_f=V(Hess(f))$ and $H_{f\circ g}=V(Hess(f\circ g))$ are  equal to $\mathbb P^n$ or are hypersurfaces of  degree $(d-2)(n+1)$.